# Prevent DB query if relation was not loaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 models, for example, `Country` and `City` with relations `one-to-many`.

When I run this code

```
$countries = Country::query()->with('cities')->get();

foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $cities = $country->cities;

    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        dump($city->country);
    }
}
```

, on the each `$city->country` call I have a query to DB

```
select * from `countries` where `countries`.`id` = ? limit 1
```

If relation (in my case `cities.country`) was not loaded with eager loading, is there a possibility to prevent making DB query on the each `$city->county` call?

I no need the `$country` variable. I need to get `null` if relation `cities.country` was not loaded in the main query.

Comment: why would you do $city->country ? You already have the country object right there....

Comment: @WouterVanDamme it just for example. I need to get `null` when I call `$city->country` in my case

Comment: That's not how laravel works. If you try to call a relationship that isn't loaded, it will load it. The way your code is laid out, there will never be an instance where `$city->country` will return `null`. If you queried `City` directly and looped the results, there might be, but you're querying `Country`, then looping, so that will never be the case.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you

Comment: I do not understand, why my question was downvoted. It is my case and I need to decide it inside my Mapper and HttpResource. This downvote is biased.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-check-if-an-relationship-has-been-eager-loaded-or-not

In my case

```
//...
if ($city->relationLoaded('country')) {
    dump($city->country);
} else {
    dump(null);
}
//...
```

Comment: That's a good check, but please let me know if it will ever be true per your use-case.. I really doubt that.

Comment: @nakov If I want to get not null but `$country` value, I must set query `with` as `with('cities.country')`. So, with this checking (`relationLoaded`) I have more control with queries to DB, main goal was reached.

Comment: My point is that this `$city->relationLoaded('country')` will never return true, because you never eager load the country from the city as you mentioned in your comment. So I don't see a point on the check at all. But you know your business better so keep on, this discussion leads to no place anyway :)

Comment: It is unfairly than this answer was downvoted. Person who make it did not understand the subject matter. Can this person explain here why was downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Why not doing the inverse then:

```
$cities = City::with('country')->get();

// this way you would loop only once:

foreach ($cities as $city) {
    dump($city->country);
}
```

Using your approach then this :

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $cities = $country->cities;

    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        dump($country);
        // here the $country variable 
       // is the same as the $city->country one, so no need to query it again..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I no need the inverse, I need to stop nesting of the relations.

Comment: you want a tree structure ? https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset#installation

Comment: You can use my edit then.. no need to call `$city->country` when within that loop the `$country` is what you already have.. so why querying it again?

Comment: I do not need the `$country` variable. I need to stop nesting relations, so I need `null` when call `dump($city->county)`

Comment: Can you please look at your question and modify it to what you need, because from what you are currently asking, this is the answer.

Comment: override the `city` in your model and explicitly put `return null;` because your use-case does not make sense at all :) If you need to return null just put `null` there and that's it.